# highcharts bar graph from json

Tags: angularjs, json, highcharts

Hi I have a json data like this. I am using angularjs

```
[
   {
    category: "NWSC Banepa",
    value: 32.91
    },
    {
    category: "NWSC Bhadrapur",
    value: 54.83
    },
    {
    category: "NWSC Biratnagar",
    value: 24.81
    },
    {
    category: "NWSC Dharan",
    value: 98.41
    },
    {
    category: "NWSC Gaur",
    value: 10.69
    },
    {
    category: "NWSC Gaushala",
    value: 93.84
    }
]
```

how can i generate bar graph from such data please help I am new to highchart

Comment: Here is a good article about the subject: http://www.highcharts.com/blog/194-using-highcharts-with-angular-js

Comment: And here's a good directive as well https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng

Comment: check this - http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-basic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi thank you all I solved it like this

in my view

```
<hc-chart chart='{{chartOptions}}'>Placeholder for generic chart</hc-chart>
```

and i created directive

```
.directive('hcChart', function () {
   return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div></div>',
        replace: true,

        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            scope.$watch(function () { return attrs.chart; }, function () {

                if (!attrs.chart) return;

                var charts = JSON.parse(attrs.chart);

                $(element[0]).highcharts(charts);

            });
        }
    };
});
```

and my controller

```
        .success(function(water_coverage) {

               var score = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < water_coverage.length; i++) {
                    score.push(water_coverage[i].value);   
                }

                var wspName = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < water_coverage.length; i++) {
                    wspName.push(water_coverage[i].category);
                }

                $scope.chartOptions = {
                    chart: {
                        type: 'bar'
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Title'
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: wspName
                    },
                    series: [{
                        data: score
                    }],
                };  
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

I am working currently on HighCharts, I am using JSON format as in Highcharts example. See if this helps :

[{
            "name": "0-18",
            "data": [1000000]
        }, {
            "name": "18-35",
            "data": [2500000]
        }, {
            "name": "35-50",
            "data": [2000000]
        }, {
            "name": "50 and above",
            "data": [1000000]
        }]